# Facebook Javascript SDK response callback not firing

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the Facebook Javascript SDK to post to the users Facebook wall. Once they have posted I want to use the response callback to show/hide some div's on the page.

My problem is that the callback(response) function isn't firing. I get no errors in the console and I have tried debugging my code with Facebook's debugging too. Still no joy. This is my first time using the Facebook Javascript SDK, so (hopefully) I've just missed something really simple.

Here is my code:

I have this at the top of my page, right after the closing body tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '647542748631249', // App ID from the App Dashboard
      status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });   

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(){
       // If we've already installed the SDK, we're done
       if (document.getElementById('facebook-jssdk')) {return;}

       // Get the first script element, which we'll use to find the parent node
       var firstScriptElement = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

       // Create a new script element and set its id
       var facebookJS = document.createElement('script'); 
       facebookJS.id = 'facebook-jssdk';

       // Set the new script's source to the source of the Facebook JS SDK
       facebookJS.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';

       // Insert the Facebook JS SDK into the DOM
       firstScriptElement.parentNode.insertBefore(facebookJS, firstScriptElement);
     }());
</script>
```

And I have this code at the bottom of my page:

```
    function shareToWall(){

    var obj =
      {
       method: 'feed',
       name: 'The 1001 Albums Quiz',
       caption: '',
       description: (
          'I scored '+numberOfChecked+' out of '+totalCheckboxes+' in the Great 1,001 Albums Quiz. Can you do better?'
       ),
       link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/albumsquiz/',
       picture: 'https://mydomain.co.uk/wp-content/themes/facebook1001/images/testimg.png'
      };
      function callback(response) {
        if(response && response.post_id) {
          console.log('Post was published.');
          jQuery('#quiz').hide();
          jQuery('#score').append(numberOfChecked);
          jQuery('#total').append(totalCheckboxes);
          jQuery('#results').show();
        } else {
            console.log('post not published');
        }
      } 
    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
```

The function 'shareToWall' is called on the click on a button on the page. The Facebook dialog is appearing just fine. I can post to my wall successfully. After the dialog closes nothing happens - this is when I need the response callback to fire.

Any help would be vastly appreciated. I have spent a very long time trying to find the solution.

Comment: I have solved this myself now. A simple 'return: false' after the onclick on my button fixed it. So simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'll answer my own question:

```
onclick="shareToWall();return false;"
```

The 'return false' fixed my problem, the callback now successfully fires.